# How to popup edited content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to edit the content in the page and popup the whole page with edited   content by clicking the button. How can it is done? i need help. Below is a piece of code, here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/420/SRw67/287/).

HTML

```
<!--just an example-->
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <form>some forms here</form>
    <p>edit here and popup.</p>
</div>
<button id="previewr">popup</button>
```

JavaScript

```
$('body').on('dblclick','p', function()
{
    $(this).attr('contentEditable', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var w = window.open('','win', 'width=500,height=300');
var html = $('body').html(); // -- get current text
w.document.open();
w.document.write(html); // -- write to new window
w.document.close();
```

[This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/SRw67/288/) displays old and new.

Comment: a kind of but how is it done with jquery and how do i save the edited page not the popup one even when i refresh the page?

Comment: Well, how is the page content loaded in the first place? Is it coming from a database, or is it just HTML in an asp or php file? If it's the latter, I'd argue that it's not a scalable design. It can be done, using PHP's [fwrite](http://uk3.php.net/fwrite) or C#'s [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx), for example.